# When to rename variables in lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I understand why renaming variables to avoid capture is important but, in the following example, I don't understand why it doesn't occur.

```
(λf.λx.f(fx))(λf.λx.fx)
```

apparently reduces to

```
λx.(λf.λx.fx)((λf.λx.fx)x)
```

but shouldn't `x` be renamed in either `(λf.λx.f(fx))` or `(λf.λx.f(fx))`? Don't they refer to different `x`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture avoidance is to avoid capturing **free** variables. "Capturing" bound variables doesn't hurt that much: In

```
λx.(λf.λx.fx)((λf.λx.fx)x)
```

the two uses of `x` are indeed different variables, but this is already encoded in the term: **In general, a new abstraction in a subterm will "overwrite" the binding of further outmost abstractions.** This is simply due to the way the evaluation of lambda terms works: If there is a new abstraction over the same variable, then the old abstraction further out will ultimately lose its effect in the subterm with the new abstraction, and the variables bound by the inner abstraction will effectively be different variables than the ones only bound by the outer abstraction.

You can try this out: If you apply `λx.(λf.λx.fx)((λf.λx.fx)x)` to some term `N`, then according to the definition of beta reduction, this term will reduce to `(λf.λx.fx)((λf.λx.fx)x)[N/x]`, i.e. the term obtained by substituting every free (!) occurence of `x` in `(λf.λx.fx)((λf.λx.fx)x)` by `N` (substitution only operates on free variables by definition). The only free occurrence of `x` in that term is the very last one; the other two `x`es in the two subterms `(λf.λx.fx)` are bound by their respective `λx`'s. So the only `x` that will be substituted by `N` is the last one, hence `(λx.(λf.λx.fx)((λf.λx.fx)x))N` will reduce to `(λf.λx.fx)((λf.λx.fx)N)` - the `x`'s bound in the subterms `(λf.λx.fx)` remain unchanged.

So the `x`'s bound by the inner abstraction and the `x` at the end of the term are indeed different variables belonging to different abstractions. Therefore it is unproblematic not to rename them during the application.

That being said, it can sometimes be useful to do such renamings for easier readability. The resulting term will be alpha-congruent to the one obtained by directly substituting without renaming.